# RPC enabled? CLI configuration?

Tags: rpc, cli

I need to determine whether RPCs are enabled in a OCW.  I am thinking that I could check `rpc_external` and/or `ws_external` in `sc_cli::commands::run_cmd` but (1) is this the best way and (2) if it is, how do I access it?  For the latter, I tried adding `sc-cli` as a `Cargo.toml` dependency but it generated a bunch of errors.

`lib.rs`:

```
    if sc_cli::commands::run_cmd::rpc_external {
        frame_support::log::info!("RPCs enabled");
    } else {
        frame_support::log::info!("RPC disabled");
    }
```

`Cargo.toml`:

```
sc-cli = { default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.28"}
```